# Disable left and top swipe gestures ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, firefox, chromium, kiosk, kiosk-mode

Hello I am trying to make a kiosk on ubuntu 20.04.

The problem that I am having is that when I run the kiosk mode, with some gestures on the touch screen it takes it out.

For example, if I make the gesture on the left edge by sliding my finger from left to right, it shows me the activities (use the gnome extension) but disables the scroll.

The other gesture that is giving me problems is the swipe from the top to the bottom (resets the window to a smaller size)

Any idea how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

U can use startx to start your app. (edit /etc/rc.local)
your app will exec before gnome. My rc.local file:

```
#!/bin/sh

#put this file in /etc directory

# setting Qt enevirment variable

export set QTLIBDIR=/opt/Qtlibs
export set QT_QPA_PLATFORM_PLUGIN_PATH=$QTLIBDIR/plugins/
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$QTLIBDIR/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH 
export QT_PLUGIN_PATH=$QTLIBDIR/plugins:$QT_PLUGIN_PATH
export QML2_IMPORT_PATH=$QTLIBDIR/qml:$QML2_IMPORT_PATH

echo "starting CalfFeeding..."

# start app

startx /home/developer/CalfFeeding/CalfFeeding -- /usr/bin/X :0 &


exit 0
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: remove gnome and use Xfce, Xfce does have gesutre function